# converting hdf to netcdf using cdo

Tags: python, hdf, cdo-climate

I was trying to convert the MODIS MCD12Q1 landcover data from hdf to nc format

I tried using the following command :
cdo -f nc remapbil,r360x180 -import_cmsaf cmsaf_product.hdf output.nc and also

I have tries the solution on following link: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/2/topics/11033

Comment: Can you tell us why you have tried failed? Given, seems correct, this could be a data issue, so providing it would also help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert hdf5 to netcdf4 in bash, R, python or NCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864357/convert-hdf5-to-netcdf4-in-bash-r-python-or-ncl)

Comment: @RobertWIlson, here is the link to one of the files of the data : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-lSLyIQ22bIcLTYm69iGvomwsluTMIRs/view?usp=drive_link.

Comment: @ClimateUnboxed , This file is in HDF format not the hdf5 . That is why these methods also didn't work out.

Comment: Sorry, but there isn't such a thing as just "hdf" there is hdf4 (depreciated and no longer supported) and hdf5, see this answer for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70837908/is-an-hdf5-file-different-from-an-hdf-file#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20types%20of,types%20are%20completely%20different%20formats.

Comment: @ClimateUnboxed when I was trying to run the cdo command it showed the  error that this type of file is unsupported.

Comment: Sorry, I tried the cdo and also all nco based solutions on your file but it is not an hdf5 file so these solns will not work.  From the MODIS website it seems these files are HDF4 (depreciated and no longer supported, no idea why they persist with it) - What about using a HDF4->HDF5 converter first? e.g. https://www.hdfeos.org/software/h4toh5-nc4-download.php    - that software can also convert directly to netcdf too, perhaps give that a try?

Comment: @ClimateUnboxed, I tried converting but it but the output was not accurate therefore, I have changed my dataset from MODIS to Landsat7.